# PHP string within quotes next to character without space

Tags: php, string

I had a lot of trouble searching google for this and it never returned what I was looking for. It seems simple enough but I can't see how its done.

```
$string = "any";
$text = "$stringway";
echo $text;
```

output: anyway

Of course it doesn't work because it is looking for a string called $stringway when I actually want it to output the string called $string with the plain text "way" concatenated on the end. I therefore need some method to separate the string from the text without actually adding a space.

I'm sure there's an incredibly simple solution.

Comment: how about `"{$string}way"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
$string = "any";
$text = $string."way";
echo $text;
```

Use the string concatenation operator `.` to combine strings.

Comment: No that's a bit long winded, especially if you have lots of strings within the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Simply enclose your variable `$string` within `{}(braces)` or you can use `.(dot)` concatenation operator

```
$string = "any";
$text = "{$string}way";
echo $text;
```

The reason to use `{}` braces is because when you write `"$stringway"` it will search for `$stringway` which leads to `undefined variable` and with braces it'll consider it as `$string."way"`

Comment: That's it! This method is perfect.